# iterate through objects which are into an array contained into an object

Tags: javascript

I'm using react.js and I have this: `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props.currentCart));`

which returns me this:

```
{
    "_id": "58f7368b42987d4a46314421",
    "userID": "58f7368a42987d4a46314420",
    "__v": 0,
    "items": [
        {
            "quantity": 1,
            "itemID": "58f6138d734d1d3b89bbbe31",
            "_id": "58f751ae3a00495f69145ae6"
        },
        {
            "quantity": 1,
            "itemID": "58f5ff55734d1d3b89bbb4a4",
            "_id": "58f755903a00495f69145ae7"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I iterate through each item and retrieve the itemID of each item (`58f6138d734d1d3b89bbbe31` and `58f5ff55734d1d3b89bbb4a4` in this case)? 
I tried in several ways, this was my last vain attempt:

```
this.props.currentCart.items.forEach(function(item){
       console.log(item.itemID)
});
```

Comment: So... I'm guessing that `forEach` doesn't work?  Do you see *anything* in your console?

Comment: it doesn't work. I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: What does `console.log(this.props.currentCart)` (lose the `JSON.stringify`) show you?  What about `console.log(this.props.currentCart.items)`?

Comment: this.props.currentCart returns: [object Object]   while this.props.currentCart.items returns [object Object],[object Object]

Comment: What browser are you using?  I'm assuming IE (Edge?) because Chrome and Firefox should print the contents and not `[object Object]`.  That being said, it seems that `this.props.currentCart.items` isn't actually an array for some reason.

Comment: I'm using chrome.

Comment: if you are using chrome and doing console.log, are you sure you are not doing console.log(this.props.currentCart.items.toString()) ? the toString returns the [object ...] output

Comment: @elpddev  No i'm not using .toString()

Comment: At this point, the real code or mocked example jsfiddle/plunkgre would help